# gnome-terminal is not opening in RHEL 8

Tags: rhel, gnome-terminal

My OS version: Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.3 (Ootpa)

I am not able to open gnome terminal for NIS user (xterm I am able to use)
If I try opening the terminal, nothing comes .

I am getting following when I try to open **gnome-terminal** from xterm:

```
# watch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/interface/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
# watch_fast: "/org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/mouse/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
# watch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/sound/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
# watch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/privacy/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
# watch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
# watch_fast: "/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xsettings/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
# watch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/a11y/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
# watch_established: "/org/gnome/desktop/interface/" (establishing: 1)
# watch_established: "/org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/mouse/" (establishing: 1)
# watch_established: "/org/gnome/desktop/sound/" (establishing: 1)
# watch_established: "/org/gnome/desktop/privacy/" (establishing: 1)
# watch_established: "/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/" (establishing: 1)
# watch_established: "/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xsettings/" (establishing: 1)
# watch_established: "/org/gnome/desktop/a11y/" (establishing: 1)
# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

My /etc/locale.conf says:

`LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/questions/608330/problem-with-gnome-terminal-on-gnome-3-12-2

Comment: Does the NIS user also have an NFS mounted home directory?

Comment: Did you try https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5442501 ? Or start it from the Gnome menus, not from within another terminal.